# Use captureVisibleTab without manifest permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

Is there a way to use captureVisibleTab without setting the `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` , `"*://*/*"` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do this. As of Chrome 11, `captureVisibleTab` requires host permission in order to capture the contents of a URL. Otherwise an extension could (for example) capture the contents of `http://www.example.com/action-token`, OCR the contents and use it for XSRF attacks, all without the user realizing that the extension has access to that private data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), then an *explicit user gesture* grants you the necessary (temporary) permissions for the current tab.

User gestures that qualify:

> - Executing a browser action
> - Executing a page action
> - Executing a context menu item
> - Executing a keyboard shortcut from the `commands` API
> - Accepting a suggestion from the `omnibox` API

Basically, the user has to manually "call" your extension from one of the visible user interfaces or through a keyboard shortcut.

This gives you the necessary permissions for `tabs` API for the currently active page, until it's closed or user navigates away from the page.